# Facebook PHP SDK - can't retrieve cover photo for event

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I've retrieved an event object and I get all sorts of properties back, like description, owner, venue, timezone, etc, but the cover photo is missing.

This is what I'm using to retrieve the object:

```
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/119780268221935"
);
```

Any idea how to get this? Is it an issue with permissions? I need this to be running in the background of my app and available to all users, so I don't really want to have to create a logged in user (i.e. myself) to be able to access this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the cover photo information by specifying it as a field in the request:

```
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/119780268221935?fields=cover"
);
```

What I would suggest doing is specifying all of the fields that are relevant to you and include the cover field as well. For example:

```
$fields = array(
 "cover",
 "name",
 "location",
 "venue",
 "start_time",
 "description"
)
$response = $facebook->api(
    "/119780268221935?fields=" . implode( ",", $fields )
);

// This is what the request will actually look like
// 119780268221935?fields=cover,name,location,venue,start_time,description
```

Here I am defining an array that holds all the fields I want and adding them to the fields parameter using [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to concatenate all the values separated by commas.

---

[Here is a link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=119780268221935%3Ffields%3Dcover%2Cname%2Clocation%2Cvenue%2Cstart_time%2Cdescription&version=v2.0) to the API Explorer with the same query.

Comment: Fantastic, that works perfectly. Any idea why they don't return it with the event object by default?

Comment: @babbaggeii - no idea! Perhaps it's a bug on their side or perhaps they feel that the cover photo is not important enough to return as a default parameter...